# PhantomJS: specify User Agent when making a call

Tags: phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to make calls to a web page, like this:

```
page.open('http://example.com', function (s) {
  console.log(page.content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I am using this in the context of Drupal Simpletests, which require me to set a special USERAGENT in order to use the test database instead of the real database. I would like to fetch the web page a specific user agent. For example, in PHP with Curl, I can do this with CURLOPT_USERAGENT before making a cUrl call.

Thanks!

Albert

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found the answer in the [useragent.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/useragent.js) file in the phantomjs [examples directory](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/tree/master/examples):

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementById('myagent').innerText;
        });
        console.log(ua);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: I am getting Unable to access network. I can access the site through my other browsers. It is internally accessible site. Is there some settings I have to setup to access from Phantom.